# Angular6 - How Render Component using service

Tags: angular

I developed Angular library with one component and service, I consumed that library in Angular Application, But how to render that library component using library Service from consumed Angular APP?

[image]

Is it possible or is there a better approach?

Comment: See https://angular.io/tutorial. Also maybe hold off on that name until you can actually dev some Angular!

Comment: Hi,
    I developed Angular library with one component and service, I consumed that library in Angular Application, But I  have to render that library component using library Service from consumed Angular APP

please guide me Is it Possible or please suggest me a new approach

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to ask. I'd suggest reading through e.g. [ask].

Comment: thanks  jonrsharpe for your response,                                                                    
    Is it possible to render component using provider service ?

Answer (score 0):

> Here are some ideas for you...

```
import { Injectable, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ComponentResolverService {

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){}

  create(cmp){
    // cmp is an actual reference to component like MyNewComponent.
    return this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(cmp);
  }
}
```

You would then call the service like...

```
// Pass in the imported reference of the component.
this.componentResolverService.create(MyNewComponent);
```

> Or you could have a key/value pair of references to components like so...

```
import { MyNewComponent, AnotherOneComponent } from './components';

export const registry = { // This could be a service or whatever
  "myCmp": MyNewComponent,
  "anotherOne: AnotherOneComponent
};
// Now we can just look up each reference using a string, instead of importing all the components.
```

> Then you could build components based on strings like so...

```
import { Injectable, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { RegistryService } from './where-ever-registry-lives';

@Injectable()
export class ComponentResolverService {

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private registry: RegistryService
  ){}

  create(cmpString){
    return this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(this.registry[cmpString]);
  }
}
```

> Once you have resolved the component, you will have to add it to the view like so...

```
// Inside a component or directive in the view...
constructor(private view: ViewContainerRef){}

ngOnInit(){
  let resolved = this.view.createComponent(this.resolver.create(cmp));
  resolved.instance['inputKey'] = stuff; // this is how you would add variables to cmp.
}
```

> Or you could just make a directive that does all of it like so...

```
import { Directive, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RegistryService } from '../services/registry/registry.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[resolve-cmp]'
})

export class HostResolverDirective {
  @Input() name; // This is a string you pass in to look up actual component reference in key/value registry.
  @Input() stuff; // This is data you want to pass to created cmp. Not needed.

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private view: ViewContainerRef,
    private registry: RegistryService
  ){}

  ngOnInit(){
    const cmp = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(
      this.registry[this.name]
    );
    const resolved = this.view.createComponent(cmp);
    // and add some data you are passing in...
    resolved.instance.stuff = this.stuff;
  }
}
```

> HTML - You would call it like so...

```
<ng-container resolveCmp name="myNewComponent"></ng-container>
```

> You can even iterate over it...

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let cmp of component.list;">
  <ng-container resolveCmp [name]="cmp.name"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

> **Update**: Regarding your updated images...

Normally, you would just import the *Angular Library* (Module) like so...

```
import { MyAngularLibrary } from '@somewhere-else';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyAngularLibrary
  ],....
```

> In your *MyAngularLibrary* you would export like so...

```
import { MyNewComponent } from './this-module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyNewComponent
  ],
  entryComponent: [
    MyNewComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    MyNewComponent
  ],....
```

> And then just use the component in your view like so...

```
<my-new-component></my-new-component>
```